# AdMob Banner not showing when im running the app

Tags: swift, ads

I'm pretty sure the code is correct but for some reason the ad doesn't show up at the top of the app when it's opened. I'm doing this in swift for my IOS app and want the ad to show up at the "home screen" when you first open the application.

```
import UIKit

import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
       bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1912006279271616/2057666171"
       bannerView.rootViewController = self
       bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        let requestAd: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        requestAd.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        bannerView.load(requestAd)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Comment: Lack of relevant tags

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me - the only difference I see with yours is setting the frame.origin property. Perhaps it defaults to (0,0) it could be hiding under the navigation bar if you have one in your view. Try placing the banner further down the screen and check.

```
let smart = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: smart)
banner.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: offsetY) // set your own offset
banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-........." // insert your own unit ID
banner.rootViewController = self
self.view.addSubview(banner)
let request = GADRequest()
banner.load(request)
```